# How to map a calculated field to JPA entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am trying to find a way to put a calculated field within a JPQL query to map to an entity in Spring Boot.

The example I have just lists a static number, but I am intending it's use to also be used for aggregates as well in the future.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findSchool",
            query = "SELECT s, 9876 as num " +
                    "FROM School s " +
                    "WHERE s.id = :schoolId)


public class School implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(FindSchoolView.class)
    private UUID id;

    @Transient
    @JsonView(FindSchoolView.class)
    private String num;

}
```

I keep getting this message when I attempt to run the query:

> "class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class com.School
> ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> com.School is in unnamed module of loader
> 'app')",

If I take out `num` as a member of the `School` entity, then there is no error.

So, how can one put a calculated value within a JPQL query to map into an entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a [formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula)

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findSchool",
            query = "SELECT s" +
                    "FROM School s " +
                    "WHERE s.id = :schoolId)


public class School implements Serializable {

    @Formula(value = "'9876'")
    @JsonView(FindSchoolView.class)
    private String num;
```

Note that the value doesn't have to be a constant but you can use any native query (despite possibly losing a bit of portability).

If it's not generated by the SQL and you don't need to save it in the db,
then you can also do this:

```
    @Transient
    @JsonView(FindSchoolView.class)
    private String num = "9876";
```

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing a separate formula annotation. You're right on the portability but that's a negative I'm willing to take.

I'll accept the answer. Cheers!